# adding nth colour to php loop

Tags: php, html, loops

Can someone help me add the below html code to php loop

The aim is to repeat the paragraph with 3 different colours 101 times

Thanks

HTML

```
p:nth-child(1n) {background: #e0ffff:}
p:nth-child(2n) {background: #f5f5db};
p:nth-child (3n) {background: #ffe4e1;}
```

PHP

```
<?php
for ($n=0; $n<101; $n++)
echo "Paragraph $n..."."<br />
\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a paragraph, you have to use the html-tags inside your echo

```
<?php
for ($n=0; $n<101; $n++)
echo "<p>Paragraph $n...</p>";
}
?>
```

your css code changes the background color of every paragraph. But doing this with modulo is a little bit hard. The `nth-child(an+b)` syntax don't allow modulo selection. Using this syntax is easy for selecting even or odd elements.

`:nth-child(n)` applies to every element (0, 1, 2, 3, ...)

`:nth-child(2n)` applies to every even element (0, 2, 4, 6, ...)

`:nth-child(3n)` applies to every third element (0, 3, 6, 9, ...)

In your case, it seems more logical to use `3n+x`, where x is 0,1 or 2

```
p:nth-child(3n) {background: #e0ffff:}
p:nth-child(3n+1) {background: #f5f5db};
p:nth-child(3n+2) {background: #ffe4e1;}
```

Comment: I think OP knows how to use `<p>` tag. After all OP has 659 reputations.

Comment: @Grimlockz I modified my post a little bit and corrected your css rules. Maybe you should have a look

Comment: sorry I think I have broken it, have missed a { somewhere -  <?php





for ($n=0; $n<101; $n++)

p:nth-child(3n) {background: #e0ffff};
p:nth-child(3n+1) {background: #f5f5db};
p:nth-child(3n+2) {background: #ffe4e1};
echo "<p>Paragraph $n...</p>";






?>

Comment: the css styles aren't part of your php code! This have to be defined only once somewhere else (external css file or a style tag inside your html head)

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
<?php
$x=1;
for ($n=0; $n<101; $n++) {
   if($x > 3) {
      $x=1;
   }
   if($x==1) {
     echo "for 1st child";
   }
   if($x==2) {
      echo "for 2nd child";
   }
   if($x==3) {
      echo "for 3rd child";
   }
   $x++;
}
?>
```

Comment: So do I just need to change the echo to show paragraph? Sorry will this also show the number of each paragragh as well

Comment: You can give different color in `if` condition. For example `if $x==1` then `color=#e0ffff` and so on. And yes it will shows the number of paragraph if you print `$n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modulo :

```
for ($n=0; $n<101; $n++) {
    $modulo = ($n%3);

    if($modulo==0){
        $bg_color = '#e0ffff';
    }elseif($modulo==1){
        $bg_color = '#f5f5db';
    }elseif($modulo==2){
        $bg_color = '#ffe4e1';
    }

    echo '<p style="background-color:'.$bg_color.';"> Paragraph</p>';
}
```